# conditionally remove row in left join or prioritize value that to show

Tags: sql, sql-server

im having trouble creating a sql script which prioritize value on a left join. so this is the scenario.

i have this query

```
SELECT a.calc_id, a.eff_post_tmst, a.event_id, a.error_flag,
b.BC_PersonId,  'Test' AS submitted_by,818674 AS transaction_id,  e.PersonType
from dbo.cnv_pen_calc a
LEFT join dbo.cnv_PpToBcPersonIdMap b on a.person_id = b.PP_PersonId
INNER JOIN dbo.cdm_person e ON e.PersonId = b.BC_PersonId
where a.event_id = 'estimate' and a.error_flag = 0 AND a.calc_id = 100019 ORDER BY a.calc_id
```

as you can see there was a left join in "cnv_PpToBcPersonIdMap" and "cnv_pen_calc" this caused duplicate calc_id on my query with different e.PersonType

this what the cnv_PpToBcPersonIdMap  data looks like

[image]

you can see that there are two records for this PP_personId that caused the duplicate of the query.

my main goal is if calc_id has duplicate like this image below
[image]

if the result has duplicate calc_ids query should display only data that has PersonType = 'Employee'
and if is doesn't have any duplicate calc_id it should leave as is.

is there a way do do that? im not expert in sql. thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you use: oracle, MySQL, sql-server...?

Comment: Which database re you using?

Comment: im using ms sql sorry about that

Comment: @GMB im using ms sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
select * from 
(SELECT a.calc_id, a.eff_post_tmst, a.event_id, a.error_flag,
b.BC_PersonId,  'Test' AS submitted_by,818674 AS transaction_id,  e.PersonType,
row_number() over(partition by a.calc_id order by e.PersonType) as rnk
from dbo.cnv_pen_calc a
LEFT join dbo.cnv_PpToBcPersonIdMap b on a.person_id = b.PP_PersonId
INNER JOIN dbo.cdm_person e ON e.PersonId = b.BC_PersonId
where a.event_id = 'estimate' and a.error_flag = 0 AND a.calc_id = 100019 ORDER BY 
a.calc_id) qry
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: thanks it worked!. you are a life saver man thanks!. i just removed the order by on the query and worked thanks a lot.